# layout folder names for large screens

Tags: android, layout, dpi

I have a question about layout folders .
What is the difference between layout-xxhdpi and layout-sw720 ?
Are they the same ? Or is sw720 used for tablets specifically and the xxhdpi is for every device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the following official documentation link:

[Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: that link is a 404 not found :p